# Displaying "\n" in c++

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in c++ and while creating a web page on "Learning basics of c++" I realised I didn't know how to display "\n" as text message in the display box.. Could someone help me out here?

PS. This is a very trivial thing but I"m very curious now.

EDIT:
I think you guys misunderstood my question.. I'm trying to display that **with the double quotes**:"\n"

I tried `cout<<""\n"";` but obviously it doesn't work

Comment: Unfortunately we can't now answer the question due to the aggressive way alleged duplicates are treated! The answer however is `cout<<"\"\\n\""`. `\\` is the escape for `\\` so `\\n` is output as the characters `\n` not newline. `\"` is the escape for `"`

Comment: it works! thanks a lot!

Comment: `std::cout << "std::cout << \"\\n\";";`

Answer (score 3):

You use \ character to display special characters

```
cout<<"\\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display it as escape sequence then you need to escape `\` like this "\\n". If you want to display it as "non-printable character" then you might want to use corresponding [Unicode control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters) (`u240A` particularly).